# deparsed match.call to a named list

Tags: r, function, call

I have a deparsed a call (to make it more human readable) in one of my functions and have included it as part of output S3 object for the reference of the end user.

```
func1 <- function(v1, v2, ...){
    return(deparse(match.call()))
}

obj <- func1(11, 22, v3 = 33)
```

The `obj` variable now contains:

> "func1(v1 = 11, v2 = 22, v3 = 33)"

Now in another function that accepts this object as an input, I would like to turn this call character vector into a named list to has the same structure as the following:

```
list(v1 = 11, v2 = 22, v3 = 33)
```

> $v1
>
> [1] 11
>
> $v2
>
> [1] 22
>
> $v3
>
> [1] 33

To be clear, I'm not willing to store the call object as is since it will not be as informative to user as it should be while they explore the S3 object (I think the programmer should handle everything and the user should just enjoy the function).

Comment: Why not just keep the un-deparsed call and deparse it when needed by the user (e.g. when printing) or even keep both?

Comment: `eval(parse(text=sub("^.+?\\(","list(",obj)))` ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper your answer is exactly what I wanted. a oneliner to be used inside my second function. I wonder why you didn't post it as an answer! please do so that I give you the green check mark (you wrote this comment 1 hour before MrFlick and you should get the green mark). In case you don't post this as an answer in the next few hours I have no choice but to accept MrFlick's.

Comment: @joran I don't want to keep both since it is waste of memory, and I don't want to add another function in my package just to print the call in human readable way when I can have it right in my function.

Comment: @Mehrad-Mahmoudian I posted as an answer now, I was hoping someone would be able to answer it without `eval(parse(text=x))` as it's better to avoid it when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following considering that the `obj` is a string as you showed in the question:

```r
eval(parse(text=sub("^.+?\\(","list(",obj)))
```

But if you would like to have it inside the function, you can do the following and avoid deparsing and parsing:

```r
func1 <- function(v1, v2, ...){
    # catch the call
    tmp_the_call <- match.call()
    
    # convert to list
    tmp_the_call <- as.list(tmp_the_call)
    
    # remove the function name
    tmp_the_call <- tmp_the_call[-1]

    return(tmp_the_call)
}


# Or as one-liner
func1 <- function(v1, v2, ...){
    return(as.list(match.call())[-1])
}

func1("qq", "ww", v3 = "ee", "rr")
```

which will result in:

> ```
> $v1
> [1] "qq"
>
> $v2
> [1] "ww"
>
> $v3
> [1] "ee"
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "rr"
> ```

Comment: you are genius. I fiddled with this question for a good 2 hours and tried different approaches, but it never occurred to me to simply replace the function name with `list` and parse and evaluate the string again.

Comment: Note after seeing your edit. If this is what you want to do, you might want to do as.list(match.call())[-1], so you don't deparse and reparse. The initial question implied that we needed to start from a string.

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
to_list <- function(x) {
  xex <- parse(text= x )[[1]]
  xex[[1]] <- quote(list)
  eval.parent(xex)
}
to_list(obj)
```

Basically we parse the string back into an expression, then swap out the original function name with the `list()` function can evaluate it to actually build the list.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly working and correct. It was posted about 1 hour later than Moody_Mudskipper's comment, plus it was in form of a function and not a standalone text which is not as fit to my problem as Moody's answer is. Never the less both of your answers are pretty much following the same logic. Hats off to you both.

Comment: This solution also replaces `func1` with `list` but it's slightly less hackish because we avoid an ugly character substitution. After toying with this solution I believe the best choice would be `as.list(parse(text= obj )[[1]])[-1]` , it's shorter and it's not a hack.

Comment: It would depend on whether or not you pass variable to the original function and if you want to preserve them as symbols or evaluate them. I assumed one would want to evaluate them.

Comment: you're right, I missed this possibility (just tested with `y <- 22; obj <- func1(11, y, v3 = 33)`)

Comment: `sapply(as.list(parse(text= obj )[[1]])[-1],eval,simplify = F)` then ?

Comment: This is a nice discussion. Actually if the evaluation is a concern, then the original answer of MrFlick works since it evaluates the expression in the parent environment where the variables do exist (considering that I adopt lines 2,3 and 4 of his code). But in my case the evaluation is not a concern and the `as.list(parse(text = obj)[[1]])[-1]` is more than enough for my need.